# What is a result of tensor product between two same vector spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

Suppose we have a vector space $V$ and we want to get another vector space $V \otimes V$. For simplicity the dimension of $V$ is 2 where its basis is $(1, x)$ for example.
What is the basis of $V \otimes V$?

Comment: $1\otimes 1, 1\otimes x, x\otimes 1, x\otimes x$.

Comment: @Billy If this vector space has commutativity, what happens to $1 \otimes x$ and $x \otimes 1$?

Comment: Tensor products of vector spaces *don't* have commutativity. You're allowed to pass scalars back and forth (so e.g. $2a\otimes b = a\otimes 2b$), but that's all. By default, $a\otimes b$ and $b\otimes a$ are usually different things. If you want commutativity, consider taking the *symmetric* product $S^2 V = \langle 1, x, x^2\rangle$ instead.